# NextJs Error occurred prerendering pages

Tags: react, next.js

```
 Export encountered errors on following paths:
        /blogs/categorias/[slug]
TypeError: Cannot read property '0' of undefined
```

```
  export const getStaticPaths = async () => {
  const res = await fetch(`api/categorias/`);
  const postAwait = await res.json();
  
  const paths = postAwait.map(node => {
    return { params: { slug: node.slug }}
  });

  return {
    paths,
    fallback: true,
  }
  
}


export const getStaticProps = async (context) => {
  const { slug } = context.params;  
  const res = await fetch(`api/categorias?slug=${slug}`);
  const data = await res.json(); 

  return {
    props: {
      singlePost: data[0]
    },
    revalidate: 1,
  };
}
```

console.log em data:
eu quero retornar o que esta dentro de blogs
mas pra isso preciso colocar data[0] e é isso que o nextjs ta bugando

```
[
  {
    _id: '601006079a0c1122f4cea4a6',
    nome: 'Notícias',
    published_at: '2021-01-26T12:42:12.473Z',
    slug: 'noticias',
    createdAt: '2021-01-26T12:07:35.163Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-01-26T12:42:12.536Z',
    __v: 0,
    blogs: [ [Object] ],
    id: '601006079a0c1122f4cea4a6'
  }
]
```

Comment: Provavelmente o dado que está na variável `data` não é um array. Para ter certeza, poderia colocar um `console.log(data)` logo abaixo da linha `const data = await res.json();`. Poderia atualizar a pergunta com esta informação?

Comment: [
  {
    _id: '601006079a0c1122f4cea4a6',
    nome: 'Notícias',
    published_at: '2021-01-26T12:42:12.473Z',
    slug: 'noticias',
    createdAt: '2021-01-26T12:07:35.163Z',
    updatedAt: '2021-01-26T12:42:12.536Z',
    __v: 0,
    blogs: [ [Object] ],
    id: '601006079a0c1122f4cea4a6'
  }
]

Comment: O erro não está neste código, está na rota:      `/blogs/categorias/[slug]`. Onde é feita esta chamada? Onde é declarada a variável `slug` que está nesta chamada?